# How to edit specific lines using AWK and copy rest as it is?

Tags: awk, sed

I have the below file named `ABCD.vasp`:

```
# A B C D
1.000000
     13.85640621        0.00000000        0.00000000
      4.61880236       13.06394496        0.00000000
      0.00000000        0.00000000       45.25483322
A B C D
   32      32      32      32
Selective dynamics
Direct
      0.00000000        0.00000000        0.00000000 F F F
      0.00000000        0.00000000        0.12500000 F F T
      0.00000000        0.00000000        0.25000000 F F T
      0.00000000        0.00000000        0.37500000 F F T
      0.50000000        0.00000000        0.00000000 F F F
      0.50000000        0.00000000        0.12500000 F F T
      0.50000000        0.00000000        0.25000000 F F T
      0.50000000        0.00000000        0.37500000 F F T
      0.12500000        0.37500000        0.06250000 F F T
      0.12500000        0.37500000        0.18750000 F F T
      0.12500000        0.37500000        0.31250000 F F T
```

The operations which I want to do on the above file:

1. I want to copy the first `9` lines into a new file named `test.vasp`
2. Line number `10` onwards, if the third column is `>=0.25` then the first column should be increased by `0.025` and the entire line should be appended to `test.vasp`
3. Line number `10` onwards, if the third column is `<0.25` then the entire line should be appended to `test.vasp`

I tried the below command which is not working:

```
awk 'NR>=10&&NR<=137{if($3>=0.25);print $1+0.025,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6;next}
$3!=0.25{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6;next}}' ABCD.vasp > test.vasp
```

Please suggest a solution to this in `awk` or `sed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'NR > 9 && $3+0 >= 0.25 { $1 += .025 } 1' file > test.vasp
```

Note that leading whitespaces and multiple whitespaces between columns might get truncated in this process. If you want to keep those then use this `awk`:

```
awk 'NR > 9 && $3+0 >= 0.25 {
   p = $1; p += .025; sub(/[^ \t]+/, sprintf("%.8f", p)) } 1' file > test.vasp

cat test.vasp
```

```
# A B C D
1.000000
     13.85640621        0.00000000        0.00000000
      4.61880236       13.06394496        0.00000000
      0.00000000        0.00000000       45.25483322
A B C D
   32      32      32      32
Selective dynamics
Direct
      0.00000000        0.00000000        0.00000000 F F F
      0.00000000        0.00000000        0.12500000 F F T
      0.02500000        0.00000000        0.25000000 F F T
      0.02500000        0.00000000        0.37500000 F F T
      0.50000000        0.00000000        0.00000000 F F F
      0.50000000        0.00000000        0.12500000 F F T
      0.52500000        0.00000000        0.25000000 F F T
      0.52500000        0.00000000        0.37500000 F F T
      0.12500000        0.37500000        0.06250000 F F T
      0.12500000        0.37500000        0.18750000 F F T
      0.15000000        0.37500000        0.31250000 F F T
```

Comment: Thanks @anbhava, it worked! The edited lines have spaces whereas the unedited lines have tabs. Is there any way awk can maintain the same spacing as the input file?

Comment: Yes check second awk solution.

Comment: Now I'm building on this answer @anubhava. Can I multiply that 0.025 with a variable of a FOR loop? I want to generate 10 different files multiplied from 0.025 to 0.25

Comment: @Sufyan: That can be done but it won't be a trivial change in this solution if you want to do it in single awk command. May I request you to post a new question so that we get more clarity and you get more answers.

Comment: here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62559210/12832411 Thanks!