# AWK inside a loop for making multiple files form single files

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have the below file named `ABCD.vasp`:

```
# A B C D
1.000000
     13.85640621        0.00000000        0.00000000
      4.61880236       13.06394496        0.00000000
      0.00000000        0.00000000       45.25483322
A B C D
   32      32      32      32
Selective dynamics
Direct
      0.00000000        0.00000000        0.00000000 F F F
      0.00000000        0.00000000        0.12500000 F F T
      0.00000000        0.00000000        0.25000000 F F T
      0.00000000        0.00000000        0.37500000 F F T
      0.50000000        0.00000000        0.00000000 F F F
      0.50000000        0.00000000        0.12500000 F F T
      0.50000000        0.00000000        0.25000000 F F T
      0.50000000        0.00000000        0.37500000 F F T
      0.12500000        0.37500000        0.06250000 F F T
      0.12500000        0.37500000        0.18750000 F F T
      0.12500000        0.37500000        0.31250000 F F T
```

The operations which I want to do on the above file:

1. I want to copy the first `9` lines into a new file named `test.vasp`
2. Line number `10` onwards, if the third column is `>=0.25` then the first column should be increased by `0.025` and the entire line should be appended to `test1.vasp`
3. Line number `10` onwards, if the third column is `<0.25` then the entire line should be appended to `test1.vasp`
4. Step-2 and Step-3 I want to repeat from `0.025 to 0.25` for `test1.vasp to test10.vasp`

I tried the below command which is not working:

```
for ((i=1;i<=10;i++));do
        outputfile=test"$i".vasp
        awk -v I=$i 'NR > 9 && $3+0 >= 0.25 {
        p = $1; p =($I * 0.025); sub(/[^ \t]+/, sprintf("%.8f", p)) } 1' $inputfile > $outputfile
done
```

Please suggest a solution to this in `awk` or `sed`

Comment: As far as I understand your question, everything goes to the file 'test.vasp'. So how do you want to generate multiple files.... what is the difference between all these files?

Comment: @kvantour I have updated the question.

Comment: do you mean the increment changes between 0.025 0.05 0.075 or the limits?

Comment: @kvantour the increment should be in steps of 0.025. For test1.vasp file, the increment is 1*0.025=0.025, for test2.vasp the increment is 2*0.025=0.050....for test10.vasp the increment is 10*0.025=0.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk` script.

```
cat incr.awk

NR <= 9 {
   s = s $0 ORS
   next
}
{
   r[++n] = $0
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
      fn = "test" i ".vasp"
      printf "%s", s > fn
      for (k=1; k<=n; ++k) {
         split(r[k], a)
         if (a[3] >= 0.25) {
            sub(/[^\t]+/, sprintf("%.8f", a[1] + .025), r[k])
         }
         print r[k] > fn
      }
      close(fn)
   }
}
```

Then run it as:

```
awk -f incr.awk file
```

Comment: I used your earlier answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62556657/12832411 and modified it a little bit. Check my answer which worked.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call awk multiple times just write to multiple output files for each line inside awk, like this:

```
{
    c=0
    for (i=0.025; i<=0.25; i+=0.025) {
        print ...whatever... >> ("test" (++c) ".vasp")
    }
}
```

Comment: Fractions inside for loop does not work in BASH, since bash can only handle integers. The main question is how to manage the printing part of my code.

Comment: This is an Awk script, where you can use fractions everywhere. Store this in a file and run it with `awk -f file`

Comment: @Sufyan you seem to be hung up on the idea of adding a shell loop outside of awk - don't do that. Just call awk once and use your existing awk code modified to loop as I show.

Comment: Oh! I totally forgot about Awk scripts. Thanks, @tripleee

Answer (score 1):

for the numerical section you can do something like this

```
$ awk 'NR>9{for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
              {f="test" i ".vasp";
               if($3>=0.25) $1=sprintf("%.8f",$1+0.25)
               print > f}}' file
```

will give

```
$ head *.vasp | column -t

==>         test1.vasp   <==
0.00000000  0.00000000   0.00000000  F  F  F
0.00000000  0.00000000   0.12500000  F  F  T
0.25000000  0.00000000   0.25000000  F  F  T
0.25000000  0.00000000   0.37500000  F  F  T
0.50000000  0.00000000   0.00000000  F  F  F
0.50000000  0.00000000   0.12500000  F  F  T
0.75000000  0.00000000   0.25000000  F  F  T
0.75000000  0.00000000   0.37500000  F  F  T
0.12500000  0.37500000   0.06250000  F  F  T
0.12500000  0.37500000   0.18750000  F  F  T
==>         test10.vasp  <==
0.00000000  0.00000000   0.00000000  F  F  F
0.00000000  0.00000000   0.12500000  F  F  T
2.50000000  0.00000000   0.25000000  F  F  T
2.50000000  0.00000000   0.37500000  F  F  T
0.50000000  0.00000000   0.00000000  F  F  F
0.50000000  0.00000000   0.12500000  F  F  T
3.00000000  0.00000000   0.25000000  F  F  T
3.00000000  0.00000000   0.37500000  F  F  T
0.12500000  0.37500000   0.06250000  F  F  T
0.12500000  0.37500000   0.18750000  F  F  T
==>         test2.vasp   <==
0.00000000  0.00000000   0.00000000  F  F  F
0.00000000  0.00000000   0.12500000  F  F  T
0.50000000  0.00000000   0.25000000  F  F  T
0.50000000  0.00000000   0.37500000  F  F  T
0.50000000  0.00000000   0.00000000  F  F  F
0.50000000  0.00000000   0.12500000  F  F  T
1.00000000  0.00000000   0.25000000  F  F  T
1.00000000  0.00000000   0.37500000  F  F  T
0.12500000  0.37500000   0.06250000  F  F  T
0.12500000  0.37500000   0.18750000  F  F  T
==>         test3.vasp   <==
0.00000000  0.00000000   0.00000000  F  F  F
0.00000000  0.00000000   0.12500000  F  F  T
0.75000000  0.00000000   0.25000000  F  F  T
0.75000000  0.00000000   0.37500000  F  F  T
0.50000000  0.00000000   0.00000000  F  F  F
0.50000000  0.00000000   0.12500000  F  F  T
1.25000000  0.00000000   0.25000000  F  F  T
1.25000000  0.00000000   0.37500000  F  F  T
0.12500000  0.37500000   0.06250000  F  F  T
0.12500000  0.37500000   0.18750000  F  F  T
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not keep the lines 1-8 into the test files.

Comment: Yes, "for the numerical section" only as you can see in the output.  In your post you wrote *"I want to copy the first 9 lines into a new file named test.vasp"*, so I thought data section doesn't include these lines?  If not, it's trivial to add.  Also format is not preserved .

Answer (score -1):

From answer to my earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62556657/12832411

This worked for me:

```
for ((i=1;i<=10;i++));do
   outputfile=test"$i".vasp
   awk -v I=$(( i * 0.025 )) 'NR > 9 && $3+0 >= 0.25 {
   p = $1; p +=I; sub(/[^ \t]+/, sprintf("%.8f", p)) } 1' $inputfile > $outputfile
done
```

Comment: This is not a an efficient solution as it calls `awk` 10 times. Please check my answer to do this in one awk command

Comment: You have 3 answers that don't do that and multiple comments advising you not to do that. You may want to reconsider doing that.